# I don't want to carry all of my old contacts on my iPhone. How could I select which groups to sync with iCloud?

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, contacts

I have about 800 contacts in different contact groups on my iMac. Some of these groups are a sort of archives. I don't want to use all my contacts on my iPhone but still I don't want to delete the permanently from my iMac.

I could select groups for sync until iCloud arrived. Now I'm syncing everything on the air, and now I need to sync all my contacts with my iphone since there is no contact group selection in iCloud.

If you know any method, how could I choose which contact group to sync with iCloud, pls let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the only way to do this is by synching your contacts via iTunes. It's not possible via iCloud. I also want this feature. Please leave Apple feedback.

http://www.apple.com/feedback/icloud.html

Answer (score -1):

There is a way!  See this link https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4245237?start=0&tstart=0

Works great

Comment: The linked article is basically a [user tip](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-2771) that explains how to have more than one iCloud account and not how to selectively sync some groups and not others. Could you expand on how multiple accounts will let the OP have all their contacts on the Mac and some on iPhone?