# Can you sync only a group of contacts from a Mac to an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, data-synchronization, icloud, contacts

I'm running iOS 6 on an iPhone 3GS. I see that all my contacts from my computer have appeared in the Contacts app on my phone. Now my contacts database on my computer is, to say the least, messy. It includes just about everyone I exchanged e-mail with over the past twenty years. Most of them are just a name and e-mail address, because I've never used this database for phone calls before.

How can I set up a useful subset of these contacts on my phone? Can iCloud sync just one group of contacts to the phone? I don't particularly want to purge all these people from my contacts database, but I also don't want to scroll through them all when trying to order pizza or do some other routine task on my phone.

I see [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34462/i-dont-want-to-carry-all-of-my-old-contacts-on-my-iphone-how-could-i-select-wh?rq=1) that this cannot be done with iCloud. How do I select specific contacts to sync using iOS 6 and iTunes 11.0.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wasn't intended to be a Jeopardy question, but I think I've figured it out.

1. On the iPhone, go to **Settings** » **iCloud** and set **Contacts** to  **Off**.
2. On the computer, turn off iCloud contact syncing
3. Connect the iPhone to the computer
4. Click on the iPhone button that appears top right in iTunes
5. Go to **Info**
6. Check **Sync Contacts**
7. Select **Selected Groups**
8. Select the group you want synced.